# Print vector elements with iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdvector

I'm trying to print elements of a vector of list pair in a hash-table program in C++.
If I use the C++11 auto it's working but if i use a iterator

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = arr_Hash[i].begin(); i != arr_Hash[i].end(); ++i)
//for (auto index = arr_Hash[i].begin(); index != arr_Hash[i].end(); index++)
    {
        cout << i->second;
        cout << " ";
    }
```

Error list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtE8u.png

How can I use the iterator here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error messages as text rather than as an image. And provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why would you try to resolve the last error first when you have 5 more errors before that?

Comment: I'm not trying to resolve the last error, just don't know how to resolve the first one.

Comment: @Andrei see Kevin's answer

Answer (score 2):

`vector<int>::iterator i = arr_Hash[i].begin()`

You're reusing the variable `i` here. Call it something else.

`std::cout << i->second;`

`i` is a `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Dereferencing it gives you an `int&`, which has no `second` member. You probably just want `std::cout << *i;`

Answer (score 0):

The iterator for `arr_Hash[i]` needs to be on the same type as the vector.

Namely, if the type of `arr_Hash[i]` is `vector<pair<int,int>>` then it's iterator needs to be `vector<pair<int,int>>::iterator`.

Howerver, you should [Prefer a range-for-statement to a for-statement when there is a choice](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-for-range).

```
for (auto& e : arr_Hash[i])
    cout << i->second << " ";
```